# Does the Secure Logger pattern need its own custom logger?

Tags: java, ssl, logging

From what I understand the Secure Logger Pattern will log everything to a secure store, through a secure pipe such as a Client Server SSL connection.

I was looking at the following example of a Client Server SSL connection in java.

http://stilius.net/java/java_ssl.php

And messages are sent through a bufferedwriter

```
bufferedwriter.write(string + '\n');
bufferedwriter.flush();
```

However it is not possible to:

```
String logMessage = log.info("hello"); 
bufferedwriter.write(logMessage + '\n');
bufferedwriter.flush();
```

as

```
log.info()
```

is a void method in sl4j.

Does this mean a custom logger is needed to log remotely, or is there a way around it using sl4j?

Comment: is it really necessary to flush after every and each log? since it is buffered, isn't it enough to flush now and then, or just before closing the stream?

Comment: this is example code from the link, its something ill have to think about.

Comment: if you are already using aspect oriented programming, it may be possible to call flush after every log, I imagine (not sure though)

Comment: or put sl4f api behind a custom facade, that allows operations after logging, like you said.